# How can I capture key events on the Mac when using OpenGL?

Tags: c

I have code that renders a triangle using OpenGL. I would like to control it using the arrow keys on the keyboard.

Anyone know how I would do this on OS X? I think I can create an Objective-C file and import NSEvent, however, I was looking to try this without the need for Objective-C. I would also like to avoid SDL.

Comment: Whatever OpenGL context-providing API you're using should come with input-handling features already. At least the good ones do, but I don't know much about what's available on OSX (isn't pretty much everything?). So maybe look up its documentation?

Comment: What do you use to create the window? Whatever it is (GLUT?), it probably comes with input handling.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use a third-party library (like SDL, which you've stated a desire to avoid...), the sane way to do this is via Objective-C, through your [`NSOpenGLView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or some custom subclass of [`NSView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) (if you want to do more advanced management of your OpenGL context manually).

Both of those classes subclass [`NSResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSResponder), which allows you to respond to mouse and key events by implementing the appropriate selector (such as `keyDown:` or `keyUp:`) in your view subclass. Make sure you also implement `acceptsFirstResponder` to allow your view to become a responder and get the key events in the first place:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
  return YES;
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event{
  unichar character = [[event charactersIgnoringModifiers]:characterAtIndex:0];
  // ...process 'character' here...
}
```

If you *are* using a third-party library to do you window management and view creation, that library should provide you a mechanism to deal with key events. If it doesn't, look and see if it offers a way to provide a custom `NSView`, and if it doesn't do *either* of those things, you should find a better library. [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) is a popular alternative.